# JSON Deserilization into Class

Tags: apex, lightning, json

**apex class**

```
public class abc {
    @AuraEnabled
    Id aID {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Id bID {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Id cID {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Map<String, String> startEndMap {get;set;}
    public abc() {
        this.startEndMap = new Map<String, String>();
    }
}
```

**lightning javascript being executed**

```
var params = {
    listOfABCJSON: [
        {
            aID: a.Id,
            bID: b.Id,
            cID: c.Id,
            startEndMap: {}
        }
    ]
}

params.listOfNewPropertyVisitsJSON[0]
    .startEndMap[this.setupDateForSalesforce(component,b.startTime)] = 
    this.setupDateForSalesforce(component,b.endTime);
params.listOfNewPropertyVisitsJSON.map(function(resource) {
    return JSON.stringify(resource);
});



var assignResource = component.get("c.assignResource");
assignResource.setParams(params);
assignResource.setCallback(this, function(response) {});
$A.enqueueAction(assignResource);
```

**apex method being called into**

```
@Auraenabled
public static Id assignResource(List<String> listOfNewPropertyVisitsJSON) {
    List<createPropertyVisits> listOfNewPropertyVisits = 
        new List<createPropertyVisits>();
    for (String propertyVisitJSON : listOfNewPropertyVisitsJSON) {
        createPropertyVisits propertyVisit = (createPropertyVisits) 
            JSON.deserialize(propertyVisitJSON, createPropertyVisits.class);
        listOfNewPropertyVisits.add(propertyVisit);
    }
    System.debug(listOfNewPropertyVisits);
}
```

I recieve the following error

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Salesforce System Error:
>   204835012-145 (-1753594556) (-1753594556)

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong with deserlizing

Comment: Are you sending a JSON string? If so you will have to change the List<String> to  a string and deserialize within the class.....PITA I know but that is what we have to do for now

Comment: Can you share `createPropertyVisits` class code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

You have to pass function parameter value in String format then deserialize them;

**apex class**

```
public class abc {
    @AuraEnabled
    Id aID {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Id bID {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Id cID {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Map<String, String> startEndMap {get;set;}
    public abc() {
        this.startEndMap = new Map<String, String>();
    }
}
```

**lightning javascript being executed**

```
var params = [{
        aID: a.Id,
        bID: b.Id,
        cID: c.Id,
        startEndMap: {}
    }];

params[0].startEndMap[this.setupDateForSalesforce(component,b.startTime)] = 
    this.setupDateForSalesforce(component,b.endTime);

var assignResource = component.get("c.assignResource");
assignResource.setParams(JSON.stringify(params));
assignResource.setCallback(this, function(response) {});
$A.enqueueAction(assignResource);
```

**apex method being called into**

```
@Auraenabled
public static Id assignResource(String listOfNewPropertyVisitsJSON) {
    List<abc> listOfNewPropertyVisits = (List<abc>) Json.deserialize(listOfNewPropertyVisitsJSON, List<abc>.class);
    System.debug('listOfNewPropertyVisits: ' + listOfNewPropertyVisits);
}
```